# Only upload updated files into Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a method that uploads XML files from a folder into a Blob Storage. Connected to that Blob Storage i have a Blob Trigger that listens to changes in the Blob Storage, takes the files and then does a PUT request to a server. I got that sorted out and working.

My problem is that when I want to update a specific file in the folder and run my code, all the files in the folder seems to be uploaded again and my Blob Trigger goes of, doing a PUT for all the files. I only want to do a PUT on the files that changed in the folder (except for my initial upload to the blob of course).

The code I have so far is as basic as my level of experience. For the import I followed a simple guide.

My code that uploads the file into the Blob Storage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
        string accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountName"];
        string accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountKey"];
        string localFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySourceFolder"];
        string destContainer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["destContainer"];

        var stringReturned = BlobSetup(accountName, accountKey, localFolder, destContainer);

        Console.WriteLine(stringReturned);
        Console.Read();

    }
    static async Task UploadBlob(CloudBlobContainer container, string key, string filePath, bool deleteAfter)
    {
        //Get a blob reference to write this file to
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(key);

        await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(filePath);           

        Console.WriteLine("Uploaded {0}", filePath);
        //if delete of file is requested, do that
        if (deleteAfter)
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }
    static async Task<string> BlobSetup(string accountName, string accountKey, string localFolder, string destContainer)
     {
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destContainer);
        //create container if not exists
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        await container.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions()
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
        });


        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(localFolder);        
        foreach (string filePath in fileEntries)
        {
            //Handle only json and xml? 
            if(filePath.EndsWith(".json") || filePath.EndsWith(".xml"))
            {                  
                string keys = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                await UploadBlob(container, keys, filePath, false);
            }

        }
        return "some response";
    }
```

My Blob Trigger that does the PUT:

```
 public static class BlobTriggerExample
{
    const string serverUrl= "theurl";
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    [FunctionName("BlobTriggerExample")]
    public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("myblob/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
    {          
        string putUrlString = "";
        string idValue = "";
        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
        myBlob.StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
        await myBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
        //Read stream
        var blobStream = await myBlob.OpenReadAsync();

            xdoc = new XDocument(XDocument.Load(blobStream));

        //Read root node(resourceType)
        string resourceType = xdoc.Root.Name.LocalName;

        //Get id value
        idValue = xdoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "id").First().LastAttribute.Value;

        //Build redirect string
        putUrlString = serverUrl + resourceType + "/" + idValue;

        //PUT
        var httpContent = new StringContent(xdoc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
        var response = await client.PutAsync(putUrlString, httpContent);    

        Console.WriteLine($"Response: {response}");
        Console.Read();

        log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes} Bytes : Response message: {response}");
    }
}
```

My guess is that I want to be able to control what files I'm uploading into the Blob Storage by doing some sort of check if the exact same file already exist. Or maybe I want to make some sort of check in the Blob Trigger before doing the PUT?

File names in the folder I'm uploading from is always the same(a must), even though some if the content might have changed.

Is there anyone that could be so kind to give me some guidelines on how I might approach this? I have been googling around for hours and I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code loops through and uploads all the files in your local folder. The blob trigger just sees that the blobs have been written and has no concept of whether or not their content has changed (or whether that matters) so it also processes all of them.

What you need to do is to compare your local files against the ones in blob storage before you upload to see whether they're new versions or not, so in your `UploadBlob` method you want something along the lines of

```
// Get a blob reference to write this file to
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(key);
// If the blob already exists
if (await blob.ExistsAsync()) {
    // Fetch the blob's properties
    await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();
    // Only proceed if modification time of local file is newer
    if (blob.Properties.LastModified > File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(filePath))
        return;
}
```

If checking the modification time isn't enough then you can also attach your own metadata (e.g. a checksum) to blobs and use that for the comparison - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a version we use in production. Note that *Metadata* is used instead of blob *last modified* property for better code flexibility & reliability. Might not fit everybody's needs but this is one way of doing it that is tested working.

```
            for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                var filePath = files[i];

                //maintains folder structure
                var blobName = filePath.Replace(selectedBuildPath, "").Replace("\\", "/");

                var blobClient = GetNewBlobClientWithMaxRetry(blobName, containerClient);

                // If the blob already exists, get the last modified tick count in the blobs metadata
                long blobLastModifiedTick = 0;
                if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var blobProperties = (await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync()).Value;
                        //this line will fail if lastmodifiedticks was not set before
                        blobLastModifiedTick = long.Parse(blobProperties.Metadata[_lastmodifiedticks]);
                    }
                    //if fail, blob last tick will be 0, aka outdated
                    catch { }
                }

                //if local file is latest, then upload else skip
                var localLastModified = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(filePath);
                var localIsNewer = blobLastModifiedTick < localLastModified.Ticks;
                if (localIsNewer)
                {
                    //print name 1st to know which gets stuck
                    //extra space to delete extra prev
                    Console.Write($"\r{i}/{files.Length} Uploading:{blobName}                  ");

                    //note will overwrite existing
                    await using var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(fs, overwrite: true, CancellationToken.None);
                    
                    //auto correct content type from wrongly set "octet/stream"
                    var blobHttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(filePath) };
                    await blobClient.SetHttpHeadersAsync(blobHttpHeaders);
                    await blobClient.SetMetadataAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { _lastmodifiedticks, localLastModified.Ticks.ToString() } });
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write($"\r{i}/{files.Length} Skipped:{blobName}                  "); //space to delete extra previous line
                }
            }
```